# Pandas dataframe: propagate True values if timestamp is identical

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Best described by an example. Input is

```
   ts    val
0   10  False
1   20   True
2   20  False
3   30   True
4   40  False
5   40  False
6   40  False
7   60   True
8   60  False
```

desired output is

```
   ts    val
0   10  False
1   20   True
2   20   True
3   30   True
4   40  False
5   40  False
6   40  False
7   60   True
8   60  True
```

The idea is as follows: if we see at least one True value inside the same ts cluster(i.e. same ts value), make all other values True that have the exact same timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on column 'ts', and then `apply` using `.any()` to determine whether any of `val` is `True` in the cluster/group.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# =====================
print(df)

Out[58]: 
   ts    val    data
0  10  False  0.3332
1  20   True -0.6877
2  20  False -0.6004
3  30   True  0.1922
4  40  False  0.2472
5  40  False -0.0117
6  40  False  0.8607
7  60   True -1.1464
8  60  False  0.0698


# processing
# =====================
# as suggested by @DSM, transform is best way to do it
df['val'] = df.groupby('ts')['val'].transform(any)

Out[61]: 
   ts    val    data
0  10  False  0.3332
1  20   True -0.6877
2  20   True -0.6004
3  30   True  0.1922
4  40  False  0.2472
5  40  False -0.0117
6  40  False  0.8607
7  60   True -1.1464
8  60   True  0.0698
```

Comment: Thanks! If I have other columns, say they are called col1, col2, col3, how do I make sure they are preserved?

Comment: I would use `transform` instead, e.g. `df.groupby("ts")["val"].transform(any)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, still truncates the DataFrame. This is not exactly what I want.

Comment: @ DSM much agreed. `transform` would be the best choice.

Comment: @BaronYugovich I don't think it truncates the dataframe. It keeps the same shape as original dataframe.

Comment: transform has the same problem of truncating my dataframe, I lose all additional columns.

Comment: so, how would this line look like  df.groupby("ts")["val"].transform(any) if I also have columns col1, col2 that I want to keep? Thanks

Comment: @BaronYugovich This can be easily solved by just transform that particular column. I've modified the code.

Comment: @BaronYugovich: to be clear, it was never that transform was truncating your dataframe, it's just that it was only returning the new version of the `val` column.  All you needed to do was store that in the frame.